# How to put the thank you slide style into a beamertheme?

Tags: beamer, themes

I have designed/hacked together a university LaTeX Beamer theme for my presentation purposes.

I have pretty much everything working as it should (could be better), but now I'd like to be able to specialize a "thank you" slide in the theme itself. I need to solve two problems:

1. Indicate the "thank you" frame somehow (e.g. if there are "backup slides" or a list of references following and the "thank you" slide isn't the last one.
2. Detect this in the `beameroutertheme*.sty` file.

I detected the title slide by using `\ifthenelse{\c@framenumber=1}` but that won't work here due to point 1 above.

Any input is welcome!

PS: for reference, the beamer theme is available on [my github](https://github.com/rubenvb/BeamerUA) and can be used by dropping the sty files and the `Images` directory alongside the main tex file (see example presentation).

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, just a strong recommendation: Do not automate such things. Making it optional with some sort-of switch, option, special command or whatever, is the way to go here.

Comment: As @yo' said. I would define a command analogously to `\titlepage` or `\maketitle` and have it print the thank you message in a nice way. Wouldn't require much code.

Comment: "Thank you" slides are far too common, but really need to go away. I would recommend against including one. `\begin{rant}` You should _say_ thank you to your audience, but leave your summary/conclusion on screen for them to soak up or to prompt questions. Have you ever seen a TED talk that ends with a giant THANK YOU? Did Steve Jobs ever end a keynote with one? `\end{rant}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As has been suggested in comments, the best thing to do is to define a `\makethanks` command, and this can be done fairly easily. For example, using the texts and formatting you already have in your `example.tex` file, you could do something like

```
% the ``Thank you'' page
\def\makethanks{%
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\@thankstitle}
  \@thanksmessage
  \end{frame}
}
% in ``article'' mode there's no ``Thank you'' page
\mode<article>
  {\providecommand\makethanks{}}

% commands for the title and message of the "Thank you" page
\def\thankstitle#1{\def\@thankstitle{#1}}
\def\thanksmessage#1{\def\@thanksmessage{#1}}
\thankstitle{Thanks for your attention! Any questions?}
\thanksmessage{Hope you slept comfortably!}
```

Adding this in one of your `.sty` files and using

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{UniversiteitAntwerpen}

\begin{document}

\makethanks

\end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

And with

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{UniversiteitAntwerpen}

\thankstitle{Thank you!}
\thanksmessage{}

\begin{document}

\makethanks

\end{document}
```

you'll get:

[image]

Of course, feel free to make any customization to the page.